# Is it possible to escape the current XPath predicate to get value out of containing predicate?

Tags: xml, xpath

This will be best illustrated with an example:

I am looking for a primary prefix name with an ancestor that contains something with SEARCH_KEY in the name, this works well.

```
//PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name [
    ancestor::MethodDeclaration//Something/Something[contains(@Image,'SEARCH_KEY')]

]
```

Now is there any way for SEARCH_KEY to be the Image property of the Name element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In XPath 1.0 it isn't possible to define and refer to range variables**.

**In XPath 2.0 one can use a [`for` expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions) like this**:

```
//PrimaryExpression
  /PrimaryPrefix
     /Name 
       [for $key in @someNameAttrib 
         return
            ancestor::MethodDeclaration
                       //Something/Something
                         [contains(@Image, $key)]  
       ]
```